# Como adicionar item em um pedido em asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou a desenvolver um projeto que pede que itens de uma pizzaria sejam adicionados a um pedido, não sendo um carrinho de compras, gerando o pedido como se fosse um programa de caixa.
Não sei como adicionar itens a esse pedido em um projeto web, alguma dica?
Lembrando que o pedido deve receber N pizzas e N bebidas e a solução esta sendo desenvolvida no visual studio 2013

segue o código!

```
 public class Pizza
 {
 public int PizzaID { get; set; }

    public string Sabor { get; set; }

    public double PrecoPizza { get; set; }

   public string Tamanho { get; set; }    
}

  public class Bebida
{
    public int BebidaID { get; set; }

    public string TipoBebida { get; set; }

    public string Sabor { get; set; }

    public string Tamanho { get; set; }

    public double PrecoBebida { get; set; }

   }

 public class Pedido
{
    public int PedidoID { get; set; }

    public double ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int PedidoAtivo { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoPedido { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public int PessoaID { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Bebida> Bebida { get; set; }

    public int BebidaID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pizza> Pizza { get; set; }

    public int PizzaID { get; set; }
    public Pedido()
    {
        this.Pessoa = Pessoa;
        this.Bebida = new List<Bebida>();
        this.Pizza = new List<Pizza>();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns problemas na sua modelagem. Do jeito que é feito, não tem como você especificar a quantidade de pizzas e bebidas pedidas. A maneira correta seria uma relação de N pra N entre Pedidos e Bebidas e Pedidos e Pizzas.

Vou arrumar pra você:

```
public class Pizza
{
    [Key]
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Sabor { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double PrecoPizza { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TamanhoPizza Tamanho { get; set; } // Tamanho deve ser um Enum 
}

public class Bebida
{
    [Key]
    public int BebidaId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TipoBebida TipoBebida { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Sabor { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public TamanhoBebida Tamanho { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double PrecoBebida { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PedidoBebida> PedidoBebidas { get; set; }
}

public class Pedido
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    public double ValorTotal { get; set; }
    public StatusPedido Status { get; set; }
    public Boolean PedidoAtivo { get; set; }
    public string DescricaoPedido { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PedidoBebida> PedidoBebidas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PedidoPizza> PedidoPizzas { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoPizza 
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoPizzaId { get; set; }
    public int PizzaId { get; set; }
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
    public virtual Pizza Pizza { get; set; }
}

public class PedidoBebida
{
    [Key]
    public int PedidoBebidaId { get; set; }
    public int BebidaId { get; set; }
    public int PedidoId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public virtual Pedido Pedido { get; set; }
    public virtual Bebida Bebida { get; set; }
}
```

Os Enums:

```
public enum TamanhoPizza 
{
    Brotinho, 
    Media,
    Grande,
    Gigante
}

public enum TamanhoBebida
{
    250ml,
    300ml,
    600ml,
    1l,
    2l,
    2leMeio,
    3l
}

public enum TipoBebida
{
    AguaSemGas,
    AguaComGas,
    Refrigerante,
    Suco,
    Cerveja,
    Vinho,
}

public enum StatusPedido
{
    Realizado,
    EmPreparacao,
    EmEntrega,
    Finalizado
}
```

Comment: Mas como colocar o pedido em uma tela só?

Comment: Ah, isso são várias outras perguntas, mas a minha sugestão [é começar lendo essas perguntas, em que eu respondo como fazer algo muito parecido com o que você quer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem).